# Javascript & HTML5 Canvas Spritesheet X Y Coordinates Issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, sprite

I want the player object in my game to have a spritesheet that is simply looped over. My spritesheet method works but I am able to place the sprite at the correct coordinates.

```
var player = {
    color: "blue",
    x: 220,
    y: 270,
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
    sprite:spriteDraw(),
    draw: function () {
        //canvas.fillStyle = this.color;
        //canvas.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        this.sprite.draw(canvas, this.x, this.y);
    }
};

function spriteDraw() {
    requestAnimationFrame(spriteDraw,null);
    //canvas.clearRect(0,0,512,512);
    var x = (count % 5) * 512;
    var y = Math.floor(count / 5) * 512
    var sprite = canvas.drawImage(img,x,y,512,512,0,0,32,32); //last two numbers scale on canvas
    if(count==5) {
        count=0;
    }
    else
        count++;
    return sprite;
}
```

I can see that it is to do with calling `this.sprite.draw(canvas, this.x, this.y);` and
`var sprite = canvas.drawImage(img,x,y,512,512,0,0,32,32);` however when I try to set draw drawImage coordinates to `player.x` and `player.y` I get "player unresolved" in the console.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to creating a looping animation using a sprite sheet?

Comment: Sorry I didn't phrase it very well. I want the looping animation from a sprite sheet which works fine to be my player's sprite sheet.

Comment: Yes, `this.sprite.draw()` does not exist, but beside that, the problem comes from the fact that `canvas.drawImage()` doesn't return anything,  so your `spriteDraw()` returns `undefined`.